# Ubuntu LDAP - does not work without connection to LDAP server?

Tags: 20.04, ldap, openldap

I've configured LDAP on couple U20 virtual servers. Everything works when those servers have connection to LDAP Server but as soon as I disconnect them I cannot login anymore.
Not even with root or with LDAP users.

Is there a possibility to allow some specific local users or have an offline copy?
I've read about sssd but somehow did not work.

Any other alternatives?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Do you have `libpam-ccreds` installed?  The `libpam-ccreds` package *should* cache LDAP creds locally when you're not around on an LDAP connection, and allow cached creds to work.  Install that, reboot, do an LDAP login with LDAP connected, then disconnect and try your auth without LDAP again.

(Originally based on the answer here: https://serverfault.com/questions/665061/caching-openldap-credentials-for-offline-use-on-laptops)

Comment: Thank you. That worked. I tried deleting one user out of LDAP group to test if he can still connect to the server.
Even after updating db that user can still connect and when I try cc_dump user is still being shown. Any idea how to solve that..?

Comment: @NASH7 because the credentials are still being cached and a local user was created.  You have to delete the local user and such, however I do not know how to clear that out of PAM.  I assume you rebooted since changing the LDAP groups, etc. of your test user?

Comment: Yes. That I did but it didn't help. Thanks. I will try to figure it out. I found no way to clear the cache.